# Rails 4 Validation: Do I ensure that an association is present with the foreign key or the association variable itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, what is the best way to ensure that an association is present?
It looks like you can test with the foreign key or the association variable itself.
I am still fairly new to Rails and so this could be a stupid question.
I am also thinking that both methods below might work.

```
# method 1:

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  # In order to validate associated records whose presence is required, 
  # you must specify the :inverse_of option for the association:
  has_many :flags, inverse_of: :region
end

class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # If you want to be sure that an association is present, 
  # you'll need to test whether the associated object itself is present, 
  # and not the foreign key used to map the association.
  belongs_to :region
  validates :region, :presence => true
end

# method 2:

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
end

class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Rails 4 Way book: "when you're trying to ensure that an association is present, 
  # pass its foreign key attribute, not the association variable itself"
  validates :region_id, :presence => true
  validate :region_exists

  def region_exists
    errors.add(:region_id, "does not exist") unless Region.exists?(region_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: FWIW, native support for foreign keys is new in Rails 4.2. See [add_foreign_key](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key)

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at validates_associated, thinking that would be what would work best here.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

In the notes for validates_associated is this tidbit:

> NOTE: This validation will not fail if the association hasn't been
>   assigned. If you want to ensure that the association is both present
>   and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use
>   validates_presence_of.

So it looks like if you're just after verifying the association is assigned, validates_presence_of should work. If you also want to verify the association is valid, validates_presence_of and validates_associated could be used together.